# Is there a Windows font that will let me use the default byobu prompt in putty?

Tags: fonts, putty, byobu

Byobu uses `MATHEMATICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET (U+27EB, Pe)` in its default prompt.  I kinda like it!  (You can see it in the video on this page: http://byobu.co/)

The problem is that, while I can get putty configured to display UTF8 characters, I get a ⟫ (or, in case your font has that character, the blank box you get when your font doesn't have the specified character) character displayed.  Other characters like á display correctly, so I'm guessing that the font I'm using doesn't have this symbol?  I also get the unintelligible character for the (r) symbol in the lower left as seen in the video on the above linked page.

I've tried the built-in Windows monospaced fonts as well as Adobe's Source Code Pro to no avail...

Comment: Would U+00BB `»` work for you?  "Right-Pointing Double Angle Quotation Mark"

Comment: Also found this website that lists all [compatible fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27eb/fontsupport.htm).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. [You're saying,](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MInQw.png) "Byobu uses the ⟫ character, but I'm getting the ⟫ character instead". Aren't these two the same thing?

Comment: @grawity You obviously didn't look at the video, and you obviously have the correct fonts.  I do not.

Comment: @Burgi Deja Vu is close, but it doesn't have the (r) symbol.

Comment: @DustinWyatt I missed the (r) one, is that the registered trademark one?

Comment: @Burgi that is correct.  Except I was wrong, it's not a (r).  It's an ubuntu logo sort of thing.  If you full-screen the video on that page, you can see it next to the "u" in the lower left corner.

Comment: I don't think there are many fonts that carry brand logos as standard...

Comment: @Burgi I'm not sure that it is a brand logo, it just reminds me of the Ubuntu logo.